# How To Get list Of Users

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using Entity Framework 6

```
public class ALLEvent
{
    [Key]
    public long Eventid { get; set; }
    public string eventname{ get; set; }
    public string AttendingUsers{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users{ get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I have an `AllEvent` Class, in `AttendingEvent` property I have a list of attending `UserId`s separated by a comma. Is there any way I can get a list of attending users in the `Users` property of `AllEvents`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with Select:

```
allEvent.Users = allEvent.AttendingUsers.Split(',').Select(
u => new User
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt64(u)
}).ToList();
```

Or with a foreach loop:

```
var users = new List<Users>();
foreach (var u in allEvent.AttendingUsers.Split(',').ToList())
{
    users.Add(new Users
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt64(u)
    });
}

allEvent.Users = users;
```

The Convert.ToInt64() method is used if you need a long type. But be aware, this could throw an exception.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zahhahw(v=vs.110).aspx

FormatException
or
OverflowException

Comment: want it in lazy loading! can it be done, like if i will get an object of AllEvents using its ID, the users list must be filled with Attending Users

Comment: Yes you can get the users if you filter them by the ids in the AttendingUsers string.
`var ids = allEvent.AttendingUsers.Split(',').Select(id => Convert.ToInt64(id));
allEvent.Users = context.Users.Where(u => ids.Contains(u.Id));`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a query for every event to get the users:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
   ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   var events = ctx.AllEvent.ToList();

   foreach(var event in events)
   {
      event.Users = ctx.Users.Where(u => 
            event.AttendingUsers.Split(',').Cast<long>().ToList().Contains(u.id)).ToList();
   }
}
```

A much better option would be to make the `Users` have a foreignkey to an event (except if it's many to many, then you'll need an intermediate table). Then you can use lazy/eager loading. At the moment the `virtual` keyword doesn't do anything in your `Event` model because there's no relation between the entities.

Edited answer because cast from string -> long is needed.

Comment: i want it in lazy loading! can it be done, like if i will get an object of AllEvents using its ID, the users list must be filled with Attending Users

Comment: @Riyaz I explain that in the end of my answer. Lazy loading is not possible this way unless you define a foreign key. Looks like you don't have one in your database though, so it's not possible.